# Multiple aggregate functions in query

Tags: sql, where-clause, aggregates

I need to have two aggregate functions in my query, but can't figure out how to filter.

I need the number of samples and the number of samples greater than 1.

something like:

```
SELECT COUNT(Samples), COUNT(Samples >1)
FROM SampleData
```

I could do a subquery, but is there a better way to filter like this?

Answer (score 2):

You can basically then the value of `Sample` using `CASE` and the result of it is the aggregated via `SUM()`.

```
SELECT COUNT(Samples), 
       SUM(CASE WHEN Samples > 1 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) 
FROM   SampleData
```

*This will work on most RDBMS though.*

Answer (score 0):

To get the *number of records*, see JW's answer. Similarly, to get the total *value* of samples, and the total *value* of samples where samples>1, use:

```
SELECT SUM(Samples) TotalSamples, 
       SUM(CASE WHEN Samples > 1 THEN Samples ELSE 0 END) SamplesGT1
FROM   SampleData
```

Answer (score 0):

In case you're using PostgreSQL, you can use the standard SQL `FILTER` clause:

```sql
SELECT COUNT(*), COUNT(*) FILTER (WHERE Samples > 1)
FROM SampleData
```